# bootstrap 4 datetimepicker how to localize

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I found the solution to this `datetimepicker` on stackoverflow. However, I wasn't able to find a solution on how I can localize it to my language.

My scripts:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'ru'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me figure out how I can localize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [documentation](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/) on "locale" the datepicker options should be:

```
{
    locale: moment.locale('ru')
}
```

---

Next to work with the locales in moment.js you have to link to "moment with locales":

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha512-LGXaggshOkD/at6PFNcp2V2unf9LzFq6LE+sChH7ceMTDP0g2kn6Vxwgg7wkPP7AAtX+lmPqPdxB47A0Nz0cMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Now instead of loading all locales, you can choose to insert russian only or additional locales you require:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/locale/ru.min.js" integrity="sha512-+yvkALwyeQtsLyR3mImw8ie79H9GcXkknm/babRovVSTe04osQxiohc1ukHkBCIKQ9y97TAf2+17MxkIimZOdw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Cloudflare moment](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js)
[Moment loading locales](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-browser/)

---

DEMO:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        locale: moment.locale('ru')
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/locale/ru.min.js" integrity="sha512-+yvkALwyeQtsLyR3mImw8ie79H9GcXkknm/babRovVSTe04osQxiohc1ukHkBCIKQ9y97TAf2+17MxkIimZOdw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Incredible. Thank you very much